# Could I do this to an infinite series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

If a had two series like so:

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \sum^{n}_{i=1} i + \sum^{\infty}_{k=1} k $$

Is it logical for me to say:

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \sum^{n}_{i=1} i = \sum^{\infty}_{i=1} i $$

Therefore:

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \sum^{n}_{i=1} i + \sum^{\infty}_{k=1} k $$

$$=$$

$$ \sum^{\infty}_{k=1} k + \sum^{\infty}_{k=1} k $$

$$=$$

$$ \sum^{\infty}_{k=1} 2k$$

Is this wrong?

Comment: Typically, we *define* $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} x_k$ as $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n x_k$ if and only if the limit exists, so this doesn't quite work. It would be correct to say that the partial sums are equal to the resulting expression, i.e. $\sum_{k=1}^n k + \sum_{k=1}^n k = \sum_{k=1}^n 2k$, but neither of these sums converge so we can't really talk about their limits.

Comment: @cemulate - Ahh so for this to be true, both sums have to be convergent?

Comment: @MaxEchendu If they are not, then the quantity $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k$ is not defined -- manipulating it does not really make sense.

Comment: @ClementC. - Ahh alright, yeah my lecturer always does tell me "STOP TRYING TO DEFINE THE UNDEFINED" haha. Thanks for the reply :)

Comment: @cemulate you should consider posting this as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, we *define* 
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} x_k = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n x_k
$$

if and only if the limit exists. So, if the limit does not exist (i.e., the sum is not convergent, then the symbol
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} x_k
$$

is not defined and manipulating it algebraically makes no sense.

So, your algebra doesn't really work, but however it would be correct to say:
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n k + \sum_{k=1}^n k = \sum_{k=1}^n 2k
$$

That is, the partial sums are additive, but neither series converges so we can't really talk about their limits/infinite sums.

Comment: I wouldn't say "if and only if the limit exists": if it doesn't, then the sum doesn't exist either.

Comment: Very well explained. Thank you :).